# Is there a dynamic setting in MySQL to implicitly limit all queries in all tables to only records with the YearID set to this year?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using PHP to access a MySql database with ~50 tables. Almost every table has a field for "YearID". My app will be starting its second year soon and I'll just keep adding records to the tables with the new YearID. Currently, my queries do not include YearID as a constraint because there is only a single year's data stored (and I wasn't thinking far enough ahead!).

I want users to be able to access previous years' data. One way to do this, obviously, is to update all my queries throughout the site to include the YearID.

Before I do that, I was wondering if there is some dynamic setting in MySql that would implicitly limit all queries to all tables to only records with a particular YearID.

For example, one query now looks like this:

```
SELECT distinct RubricPK, tas.DisplayOrder, s.IDENTIFIER
    FROM Rubric r
    JOIN TeacherAssessedStandards2 tas ON tas.STANDARDID=r.EL_StandardID AND tas.SLorEL="EL" AND 
     tas.SectionDCID = ?
    JOIN Standards s ON s.StandardID = tas.ParentStandardID
    ORDER BY tas.DisplayOrder, s.IDENTIFIER
```

There is no YearID included in this query.

Is there a MySQL setting I can change with PHP so that the query above will only pull from records in each table where YearID=2020?

Or should I get to work editing all my queries to include a YearID constraint?

Comment: Nope, there isn't. A [bad] workaround could be to create another database for the next year. It doesn't sound too good anyway, since you would need to create one database every year.

Comment: I suspected as much. Thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: Not to criticize but this is an architectural design defect. It will be expensive to fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to achieve that directly via a setting. What you can do is write a few lines of $scripting_language to find all the tables via the information_schema and create a VIEW based on each one in a separate database. For example:

```
CREATE VIEW DB2020.table_name AS SELECT * FROM MainDB.table_name WHERE YearID = '2020';
```

Then give your users SELECT access only to DB2020 database.

Comment: Ahh -- this automates creating the views nicely. Since the view needs to have a different name than the base table, I'd still need to adjust every query to reflect that, I think. But a good, workable, approach if I go that route. I don't have enough reputation to upvote your answer, yet, but I'll come back when I do.

Comment: You shouldn't have to adjust the queries because you can the views can have the same names as the tables, because they will be in a different database. You can always mark it as the correct answer. :-)

Comment: So if I understand your solution correctly, I'd use my current database to keep adding records each year, but create views for individual years and store those views in a separate database. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, one database per year, each containing views that show only the records for that year. The only thing you need to toggle is the database name in your app to see a different year's records.